# Why meta tags for no caching don't work in a Web site and the HTML pages load from cache?

Tags: html, caching

I have this Web site: https://fascinatingdreams.com/fd1/index.html. I have set cache behavior to no caching in the meta tags, in the head section of the HTML files of the site, but the site fails to respect those caching directives, and the HTML files load from the cache. Developer tools show that the headers have cache-control: max-age=0.

What I want to achieve is that the HTML pages will not load from the cache.

This is the HTML code that I use to prevent caching of the Web pages:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: what type of resources are cached by your browser?

Comment: Hello Alireza. All resources are currently cached by the browsers.